# R: Debug glm "subscript out of bounds" in ExtremeBounds command

Tags: r, glm

I'm running code using ExtremeBounds and glm (logit) through several specifications and sometimes I run into the following problem:

```
Data <- data.frame(var1=rbinom(30,1,0.2),var2=rbinom(30,1,0.2),var3=rnorm(30),coll1=rep(3:32),coll2=rep(1:30))
eba <- eba(data=Data, y="var1", 
       free="var2", 
       doubtful=c("var3","coll1","coll2"),
       reg.fun=glm, k=1, vif=7, draws=50, weights = "lri", family = binomial(logit))
```

where the error message is:

```
Error in reg.summary$coefficients[variable.label, 1] : 
subscript out of bounds
```

Since my dataset is quite big, I have no idea which variable causes this problem in my actual application. Does anyone know one of the answers to these questions:

1. how can I see which variable causes it?
2. how can I drop it automatically (maybe with a message like: "coll2 omitted due to collinearity")
3. Am I right that this problem is caused by glm?

Comment: try `options(error=recover)` to get dropped into debug/browser mode when the error accurs?

Comment: thanks, I haven't really gone into these debugging options yet. But as far as I can see this just tells me that the error is somewhere in the run.eba or run.regressions part, right? It doesn't tell me which variable fails...

Comment: no, but you can inspect the current values of variables at the time of the failure

Comment: could you be more specific? I just see the general eba command highlighted when I choose option 4, for example

Comment: your example isn't reproducible -- where does `se.robust` come from?

Comment: (I can reproduce if I just leave it out)

Comment: sorry, isn't needed here, you're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting as an answer, a bit long for a comment:

- set `options(error=recover)`
- running the code above (without `se.fun=se.robust`) gives

```
1: eba(data = Data, y = "var1", free = "var2", doubtful = c("var3", "coll1", "
2: .eba.wrap(formula = formula, data = data, y = y, free = free, doubtful = do
3: run.eba(y = y, v = focus, x = free, combinations = comb, data = data, level
4: run.regressions(y, v, x, combinations, data, level, vif.max, vars.labels, v
```

I choose option #4 (the lowest level)

I can run `ls()` to see all the variables that exist within this scope.  Since I know the problem occurs with `reg.summary$coefficients[variable.label, 1]` I can try

```
Browse[1]> variable.label
#   coll2 
# "coll2" 
Browse[1]> str(reg.summary$coefficients)
#  num [1:3, 1:4] -0.9154 0.9436 -0.0504 1.1159 0.9728 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "var2" "coll1"
#   ..$ : chr [1:4] "Estimate" "Std. Error" "z value" "Pr(>|z|)"
```

That shows me that `reg.summary$coefficients` has apparently dropped the `coll2` variable ...

Unfortunately I don't know enough about what `eba()` is doing to know how to proceed farther with diagnosis ... if you do, you can inspect the `reg.summary` object further to try to figure out what's going wrong ...

Comment: thanks a lot Ben! I'll leave the question open for now, maybe the author of the package drops in. I'll have a fresh look at it tomorrow.